# Get events from Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When we create a Custom Conversion with FB Graph API, we can define the `event` name param. I'm trying to find how can I get first my Custom Events, and then select some custom event to parse to `event` name.
How can I do it?
Take a look at Custom Conversions docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/custom-conversion/v17.0

Comment: On Facebook docs, it means there is no way to GET Custom Events by Pixel ID: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ads-pixel/events/v17.0  :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own solution: I used the Ads Pixel Stats endpoint, that you can see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ads-pixel/stats/v17.0

Basically, I made a request to `/{ads-pixel-id}/stats` endpoint by passing the `aggregation` param with `event_total_counts` value:

[https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/{ads-pixel-id}/stats?aggregation=event_total_counts](https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/%7Bads-pixel-id%7D/stats?aggregation=event_total_counts)

That will returns a list of active events (custom and standard) for the pixel with a count of occurrences. Do you can also parse another params, as you can see in the documentation above.

Answer (score -2):

To retrieve your Custom Conversions and select specific events to parse the event name, you can use the Facebook Marketing API. Here's how you can do it using Python and the `requests` library:

1. **Get Your Custom Conversions:**

First, you need to make a GET request to retrieve your Custom Conversions. You will need to provide your Access Token and Ad Account ID in the request URL.

> import requests
>
> ```
> access_token = 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'
> ad_account_id = 'YOUR_AD_ACCOUNT_ID'
>
> url = f'https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/{ad_account_id}/customconversions'
> params = {
>     'access_token': access_token
> }
>
> response = requests.get(url, params=params)
> custom_conversions = response.json()
> ```

This will give you a list of your Custom Conversions, including the event names associated with each conversion.

2. **Select Specific Custom Event and Parse Event Name:**

Now that you have the list of Custom Conversions, you can select a specific conversion and parse the event name. Let's say you want to select the first Custom Conversion:

> if 'data' in custom_conversions and len(custom_conversions['data']) >
> 0:
> selected_conversion = custom_conversions['data'][0]
> event_name = selected_conversion.get('event_name', '')
> print(f'Selected Event Name: {event_name}') else:
> print('No Custom Conversions found.')

In this example, `event_name` contains the name of the selected Custom Conversion event.

Make sure to handle errors and edge cases appropriately in your code, and also consider pagination if you have a large number of Custom Conversions.

Please note that you need to have the necessary permissions and a valid Access Token to access your Custom Conversions data through the Facebook Marketing API.